# Google Maps API - Markers not showing up from external JSON

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to use the Google Maps API to display many many multiple map markers, the data is in a series of arrays in an external JSON file.

snippet of relevant HTML/Javascript

```html
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var map;
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.8039941, -77.863459),
          zoom: 14,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            mapOptions);
      }
        //get JSON data
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON("crime_maps_test.json", function(json1) {
          $.each(json1, function(key, data) {
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng); 
            // Creating a marker and putting it on the map
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng,
                title: data.Incident
            });
            marker.setMap(map);
          });
        });
      });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_key&callback=initialize"></script>
```

crime_maps_test.json snippet (actual file contains a couple hundred arrays)

```js
[
  {
     "Incident": "PSU201701139"
    ,"Occurred": "3/25/17 23:25"
    ,"reported": "3/25/17 23:25"
    ,"nature of incident": "Resident Assistant reported the odor of marijuana, origin not located"
    ,"offenses": "Possession of Small Amount of Marijuana"
    ,"location": "Porter Hall"
    ,"disposition": "Open"
    ,"lat": 40.8008254
    ,"lng": -77.8587917
  },
  {
     "Incident": "PSU201701136"
    ,"Occurred": "03/25/2017 9:25 PM to 9:30 PM"
    ,"reported": "3/25/17 21:31"
    ,"nature of incident": "Visitor observed highly intoxicated"
    ,"offenses": "Public Drunkenness"
    ,"location": "Bryce Jordan Center"
    ,"disposition": "Open"
    ,"lat": 40.8086228
    ,"lng": -77.8642905
  },
  {
     "Incident": "PSU201701134"
    ,"Occurred": "03/25/2017 8:52 PM to 8:58 PM"
    ,"reported": "3/25/17 20:58"
    ,"nature of incident": "Resident Assistant reported the odor of marijuana, origin not located"
    ,"offenses": "Possession of Small Amount of Marijuana"
    ,"location": "Curtin Hall 5Th Floor"
    ,"disposition": "Open"
    ,"lat": 40.8051407
    ,"lng": -77.8633569
  }
  ]
```

I am hosting the project on GitHub to avoid cross referencing errors. While the map is displaying and the developer's tools console is not logging any errors, the markers are not displaying. Am I missing something in my code that is preventing the markers from displaying? Anyone know what is or might be causing this issue?

Comment: [The posted code works with the posted JSON](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/L23L536x/), maybe you are having a problem loading it, maybe add some error handling to the $getJSON to see why you aren't getting a result)

Comment: The posted JSON contains only 3 arrays. The actual JSON contains a couple hundred arrays. Do you have any idea how I would add the error handling to the $getJSON?

Comment: Is your JSON file valid? Did you check it? If your code works with 3 items, why would it fail with "hundreds"? Validate your JSON file with for example [http://jsonlint.com/](http://jsonlint.com/) and as suggested, try to debug your  get request results.

Comment: How to debug? Use your javascript console. `console.log(json1)` above your `$.each` loop should be a good start. Then inspect your console and see what's in there.

Comment: MrUpsidown yeah there were several invalid entries. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was an issue with several of the JSON entries. Should have validated the data.